# Text input at the Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap to make a navigation bar and when I try to add a search bar it goes below the other elements instead of beside them.

I have jQuery and the Bootstrap JavaScript imported after everything, along with the Bootstrap CSS imported in the head tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <form class="navbar-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
         </form>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: What element would I use it on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: the result]

1. You can use the [Default navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) as a sample.
2. Place the form outside of the `<ul></ul>` block.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```